# traverse through Parent-Child objects and construct path value using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have object like below

```
var childitems = function(child) {
    return {
        id: item.id,
        type: child.type,
        path: child.title,
        parent: child.parent,
        hasChildren: true | false (based on some condition)
    };
};
```

also, I have function which returns all child elements based on 'hasChildren' and 'Parent' attributes from above object structure which again returns data as in childitems format. Basically, if hasChildren is true that level has 'n' childs within it.

Can underscore.js can do deep watch or using something like _.map can get all path values starting from parent object to all child elements?

Finally outcome of path required is.
**Parent/Child1/Child11/Child111**

**Parent/Child1/Child12/Child112**

(Child1 in above example has two child elements child11 and child12)
**Parent/Child2/Child22/child222**

**Parent/Child2/Child22/child333**

(Child22 in above example has two child elements child222and child333)

Comment: What do you want as outcome? New object with flattened keys or just an array with paths?

Comment: array with the paths

Answer (score 0):

I'm using function like this, it construct paths for all keys recursively. Hope this helps

```
var getKeysFlat = function(obj) {
  /* helper function to get keys of the object recursively,
     e. g {foo: 42, bar {foo: 42}} will have following keys:
     ['foo', 'bar/foo']
   */
  var result = [];
  var recurse = function (obj, keyPrefix) {
    if (keyPrefix !== ''){
      keyPrefix = keyPrefix + '/';
    }
    _.each(obj, function (val, key){
      if (_.isObject(val)){
        recurse(val, keyPrefix + key);
      } else {
        result.push(keyPrefix + key);
      }
    });
  };
  recurse(obj, '');
  return result;
};

console.log(getKeysFlat({
  value: 2, 
  child1: {
    child11: 3
  },
  child2: {
    child22: {
      child222: 4
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: its working for the case provided in the input. My object above 'childitems 'is different and I don't know before hand if a level has child within it, I need to find out it using getChldrens(item) which again returns me object of type 'childitems'.